# Java ComboBox What controls where list will display?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Possibly an odd question but how can I change how my Java Swing combo box displays its list of items?  The default behavior is for the list to be displayed below the combo box.  There are times, when the combo box is low on the screen, that the list is displayed above the combo box.  Is there a way to force it to always display above?  What if I wanted the list to "pop out" and float above the form displaying larger than the normal size?  Are these things possible?

Thanks
ST

Comment: Good to know that I wasted time anwering the crosspost in the Sun forums. That won't happen again. The solution given here works for a single LAF only. The solution over there would work on any LAF.

Answer (score 2):

The display location and size of the popup is not decided by the JComboBox itself, but by the installed look & feel. You can either provide your own look & feel or wrap the currently installed one by overriding  `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI#createPopup()` to provide your own implementation of  `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup#getPopupLocation()` and `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup#computePopupBounds()`.